# What is the difference between TFRecordDataset and FixedLengthRecordDataset?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, dataset

It will be great to get a use case possibly from a project and explain the use of each. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TFRecordDataset`, `FixedLengthRecordDataset` as well as `TextLineDataset` are classes of `Dataset`.

> Dataset is a base class containing methods to create and transform datasets. Also allows you initialize a dataset from data in memory, or from a Python generator.

> Since release 1.4, Datasets is a new way to create input pipelines to TensorFlow models. This API is much more performant than using feed_dict or the queue-based pipelines, and it's cleaner and easier to use.

As a use case, you can think of the pre-processing of data to feed it into a model for training (Examples in the links below are pretty self-explanatory).

- [TFRecordDataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/TFRecordDataset): Reads records from TFRecord files ([Example 1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/dec8e0b11f4f87693b67e125e67dfbc68d26c205/tensorflow/python/data/experimental/ops/writers.py), [Example 2](http://tensorflow.biotecan.com/python/Python_1.8/tensorflow.google.cn/api_guides/python/reading_data.html#file_formats#:%7E:text=Standard%20TensorFlow%20format)).

```
#Python
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset("/path/to/file.tfrecord")
```

- [FixedLengthRecordDataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/FixedLengthRecordDataset): Reads fixed size records from binary files ([Example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/dec8e0b11f4f87693b67e125e67dfbc68d26c205/tensorflow/lite/tutorials/dataset.py)).

```
#Python
images = tf.data.FixedLengthRecordDataset(
      images_file, 28 * 28, header_bytes=16).map(decode_image)
```

- [TextLineDataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/TextLineDataset): Reads lines from text files.

See this [documentation](https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/09/introducing-tensorflow-datasets.html) (TextLineDataset example included)

Comment: Thanks Ksign, could you share an example of the output for both TFRecordDataset & FixedLengthRecordDataset

Comment: Did you try it? Please remind that the Stackoverflow community is here to help on code issues but a [minimum effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) is asked from the posters before posting questions. If you have trouble getting the output, you can edit your question with the code you tried and we will try to help.